# so I build this code generator and is not up to par

Tags: javascript

I got help on building this code generator, when I check it on JSHint like my teacher ask it shows 5 undefined variables even tho im storing the objects or references on a string as you can see below, what suggestions do the community has for me to fix this, it works just fine but I donw know why they check it on jshint, I use my self sublime text and intellyJ for editors and they do not show me the errors that JShint shows, 5 undefined variables, and in the console does not show me errors ether.

```
var quotes = [   
quoteOne = {
        quote : 'I meant what I said and I said what I meant.',
        source : 'Dr. Seuss',
        citation : 'dont know',
        year : '1990'
    },
        quoteTwo = {
        quote : 'Truth is everybody is going to hurt you: you just gotta find the     ones worth suffering for.',
        source : 'Bob Marley',
        citation : 'Smoke session',
        year : '1989'
    },
        quoteThree = {
        quote : 'Never interrupt your enemy when he is making a mistake.',
        source : 'Napoleon Bonaparte',
        citation : 'I dont know',
        year : '1991'
    },
        quoteFour = {
        quote : 'Fear is the main source of superstition, and one of the main sources of cruelty. To conquer fear is the beginning of wisdom.',
        source : 'Bertrand Russell',
        citation : 'I dont know',
        year : '1992'
    },
    quoteFive = {
        quote : 'Curiosity will conquer fear even more than bravery will.',
        source : 'James Stephens',
        citation : 'I dont know',
        year : '1993'
    }];
//this function picks a quote in random from my quote storage and returns how to print on the page.
    function getRandomQuote() {
        var item = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()* quotes.length)];
        return '<p class="quote">' + item.quote + '<p class="source">' + item.source + '<span class="citation"><br>' + item.citation + '<br><span class="year"><br>' + item.year + ', ' ;
    }
 //this function prints the quote when the button is click
    function printQuote() {
        document.getElementById('quote-box').innerHTML = getRandomQuote();
        document.getElementById('loadQuote').addEventListener("click", printQuote, false);
    }

    console.log(printQuote());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5 undefined variables are `quote1`, `quote2`... `quote5` in your array declaration.

Your array should look like:

```
var quotes = [   
    {
        quote : 'I meant what I said and I said what I meant.',
        source : 'Dr. Seuss',
        citation : 'dont know',
        year : '1990'
    },
    {
        quote : 'Truth is everybody is going to hurt you: you just gotta find the     ones worth suffering for.',
        source : 'Bob Marley',
        citation : 'Smoke session',
        year : '1989'
    },
    {
        quote : 'Never interrupt your enemy when he is making a mistake.',
        source : 'Napoleon Bonaparte',
        citation : 'I dont know',
        year : '1991'
    },
    {
        quote : 'Fear is the main source of superstition, and one of the main sources of cruelty. To conquer fear is the beginning of wisdom.',
        source : 'Bertrand Russell',
        citation : 'I dont know',
        year : '1992'
    },
    {
        quote : 'Curiosity will conquer fear even more than bravery will.',
        source : 'James Stephens',
        citation : 'I dont know',
        year : '1993'
    }];
```

I'm surprised your original code is valid JavaScript - So I've learnt something today :)  Everything else looks good to me.

Comment: yeah I know there many ways to skin a cat, but yes this was not the issue, I reported a bug on JSHint they fix something on the back end now my code shows no errors on the syntax or undefined for that matter, but yeah there so many people that code differently and cool, to me coding is a way of art, the way it flows is amazing, and always trying new ways of placing rare code that looks incorrect but is valid.

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't trying to be negative with my commend re: valid javascript.  

Anyway, JSHint was absolutely correct to flag the 5 undefined variables - `quote1` ... `quote5` were not defined anywhere in your code - so they were being assigned as global variables (Which is a bad thing)